# How to convert spark sql dataframe to numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, apache-spark, dataframe

I'm using pyspark and imported a hive table into a dataframe.

```
df = sqlContext.sql("from hive_table select *")
```

I need help on converting this df to numpy array. You may assume hive_table has only one column.

Can you please suggest? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can:

```
sqlContext.range(0, 10).toPandas().values  # .reshape(-1) for 1d array
```

```
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8],
       [9]])
```

but it is unlikely you really want to. Created `array` will be local to the driver node so it its rarely useful. If you're looking for some variant of distributed array-like data structure there is a number of possible choices in Apache Spark:

- [`pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#module-pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed) which provides a number of [distributed matrix](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html#distributed-matrix) classes.
- [`sparkit-learn`](https://github.com/lensacom/sparkit-learn#quick-start) `ArrayRDD`.

and independent of Apache Spark:

- [Dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) [`dask.array`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array.html).